# web scraper is being denied by the website even after implementing a user-agent

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently creating a web crawler to gather data from a website for a school project. This issue is that I'm getting the following error code (only from this one webpage):

```
<h1>You are viewing this page in an unauthorized frame window.</h1>
0
[Finished in 5.4s]
```

Here is the full code:

```
#Creating my own webcrawler

from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import urllib.request


myurl = 'https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/data-feeds'
myReq = (myurl)

req = urllib.request.Request(
    myurl, 
    data=None, 
    headers={
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'
    }
) 

#opening my connection, grabbing the page
uClient = uReq(myurl)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

#html parsing
page_soup = soup(page_html, 'html.parser')

print(page_soup.h1)

containers = page_soup.findAll('td rowspan="1"',{'class':'x-hidden-focus'})
print(len(containers))
```

As you can see, I even added a user-agent but I'm still getting this error message. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the first parameter on the 'findAll' method won't help you, so the issue might have nothing to do with the HTTP request-response cycle.

I queried the url you're using and all possible attributes of all 'td' elements on the document are:

```
{'class': ['xml-file-size', 'file-20']}
{'class': ['xml-file-type', 'file-20']}
{'colspan': '2', 'class': ['xml-file-type', 'file-20']}
{'rowspan': '3'}
{'colspan': '2'}
{}
```

Which makes querying for 'rowspan' of 1 and 'class' 'x-hidden-focus' return the empty list.

Try on the second to last line:

```
containers = page_soup.findAll('td', {'colspan'='1', 'class':'file-20'})
```

or:

```
containers = page_soup.findAll('td', {'rowspan': '3'})
```

or even just:

```
containers = page_soup.findAll('td')
```

Is up to you which specific 'td' elements you're looking for.

Check out the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function) also to learn about more ways to use BeautifulSoup, including passing functions as arguments, etc.

Comment: Hey, appreciate the help! The second version worked for me, and gave me 120 results. Perfect :)